# getElementsByTagName is not working with DOM method addEventListener

Tags: javascript, dom, addeventlistener, getelementsbytagname

```js
var x=document.getElementsByTagName("button");
x.addEventListener("click", function() {alert('You Just Clicked !!');});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Its Practice</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hi there</h1>
<button>Click Me !!</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="practice2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName` is a array like collection. Use `for loop` on it to access each element and add event listener to it

Comment: Thanks @brk for helping me out of this confusion.

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName` function returns a list of objects,
according to your code x will be `HTMLCollection [button] 0: button length: 1`
so you can not call `addEventListener` on x.

use this instead:

```
x[0].addEventListener("click", function() {alert('You Just Clicked !!');});
```